# Dependency Injection not working in angular app

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am having trouble in accessing the properties of my service. As you can see in the pictures below, Decorators and imports are in order and the service itself was properly added and injected. I don't seem to understand what is causing the error, since the "normal procedure" of dependency injection is being respected. The service in question is the Register service. 
Any advices to resolve the problem? Thanks in advance.

**app.module.ts**

[image]

**register.component.ts**

[image]

**register.service.ts**

[image]

Part of the **register.component.html**

[image]

Errors I am getting(all similar):

[image]**

Files:

[image]

Comment: The error that you're gettin are pretty straight forward. The firstName property is not part of the RegisterComponent. you may want to access that from the myform that you placed in the RegisterService. 

RegisterService is handling the form and should not do that. Is not really best practice. Move the form in the component.

Then you can easily use the reactive forms

Comment: I will follow your advice. But shouldn't angular be able to access the properties of my service? I mean, it's an normal class instance being injected and made "public" for use.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pointing 2 mistakes in the above code snippet.

1. Yes Obviously while implementing **OnInit** life cycle hook in the RegisterService class. Since **all life cycle hooks are for components not for services.**
2. Since you already added below line in the RegisterService class.

> @Injectable({
>         providedIn: 'root'
>       })

You **don't need to add this service class again in the provider array of app.module.ts** class. Since `@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})` already means you injected the service at root level.

Answer (score 0):

services didn't support component lifecycle like OnInit etc

your service can be like this

```
@Injectable()
export class FormService {
  contactForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createContactForm();
  }

  createContactForm(){
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName: [''],  
      email: [''],
      message: ['']
    });
  }
}
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-form-service?file=src%2Fapp%2Fform.service.ts)

Answer (score 0):

Only Directive and component instances have a lifecycle so register.service.ts is created like component